Interpolate Image from Sparse Color Blobs by Distance Metric
Image processing: I'm looking for an interpolation/fill function that takes as an input a mostly black image with some scattered color shapes (pic 1). The function should fill all black pixels based on distances to the nearest color shapes (pics 2, done manually). The filled-in interpolated colors should blend to some controllable degree (pic 2 & 3) I can work with Python (OpenCV,scikit-image,Pillow), Mathematica, MATLAB, so pointers to functions in any of them are fine.


I will sketch my solution and then will add code in Julia.

Get the unique colors of the image (Without black) and the coordinates per color.
Per color build a KD Tree to easily find given a coordinate the distance to each color. I define the distance as the minimum distance to each color blob.
Once I have a distance per color I create a weight. Something like $exp \left( - \frac{{d}^{2}}{2 {\sigma}^{2}} \right)$ where $d$ is the distance.
Normalize the sum of weights to have a unit sum.
Use the weights to interpolate the output color.

You may use different kind of functions to generate $\sigma$ per color clusters depending on the number of pixels.
I implemented the method for a constant $\sigma$:


Smaller $\sigma$ will yield less blending.
Tough probably one should implement adaptive $\sigma$.
The problem is mostly about using the correct data structures to make the calculation fast.
The concept of the interpolation is pretty straight forward.

The code is available on my StackExchange GitHub Repository (Look at the SignalProcessing\Q95814 folder).

Thanks! I'll give it a try later today.

I get a function/method error (link below). I used the JuliaImageProcessing.jl from your Github, if that's what the error is about. https://pastebin.com/zVviSi7X

@MrSparkly, It seems you're trying a different image, could it be? Could you share the exact image files you use?

Yes, it's a different image. It's still an RGB png (no alpha), but bigger 1024x1298. I can't send it, as its content is tied to a certain project. I just tried your code on my sample png in my OP above (both my original, and as dl'd from StackEx) and I get the same error. I tried both interactive, and command line (julia Q95814.jl) Does your code need a certain image type? I can try to tweak the code or the image, but I'm not sure what's needed. I installed the newest Julia packages, maybe the versions are mismatched. Thanks for your help.

It seems your png is interpreted with alpha channel which my function does not support. I will add support for that.

@MrSparkly, I pushed an update with support for RGBA images. Make sure you define the environment as in the upper section of the script.

My png doesn't have alpha (visible to me) unless there's some flag in the file that makes it look like it. Still the same error: https://pastebin.com/nCJ9t69b Pkg status with versions https://pastebin.com/VRxXrcVp Are we on the same pkg versions? I realized I don't have to send my whole image, a small part will do, so I'll send it to you. Thanks.

@MrSparkly, You can clearly see Julia parse it as RGBA (Namely Alpha RGB) as in ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching ConvertJuliaImgArray(::Matrix{RGBA{FixedPointNumbers.N0f8}}). You better follow the instruction in the top of the script file how to activate and use the packages.

@MrSparkly, Why did you remove the mark and up vote? Was something wrong?
